# Comparing two objects with JUnit shows strange behaviour

Tags: java, junit5

I'm writing a JUnit test method for the class `AbsorptionScheme`, which takes so-called `AbsorptionBlocks` and sorts them into an array of absorptionBlocks. What I wanted to test is if the sorting works fine. So I created two absorptionScheme object and filled both with the same absorptionBlocks, but the first one of them unsorted and the second pre-sorted. Then I wanted to use JUnit's `assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)` function to make sure both AbsorptionScheme object are identical. Although the toSting method returns identical strings, JUnit still tells me both objects are not identical.

Here's JUnits assessment:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: info.rueth.fpucalculator.calc.AbsorptionScheme<Absorption Scheme: (1FPU -> 3h) (2FPU -> 4h) (3FPU -> 5h) (4FPU -> 6h) (6FPU -> 8h)> but was: info.rueth.fpucalculator.calc.AbsorptionScheme<Absorption Scheme: (1FPU -> 3h) (2FPU -> 4h) (3FPU -> 5h) (4FPU -> 6h) (6FPU -> 8h)>
Expected :info.rueth.fpucalculator.calc.AbsorptionScheme<Absorption Scheme: (1FPU -> 3h) (2FPU -> 4h) (3FPU -> 5h) (4FPU -> 6h) (6FPU -> 8h)> 
Actual   :info.rueth.fpucalculator.calc.AbsorptionScheme<Absorption Scheme: (1FPU -> 3h) (2FPU -> 4h) (3FPU -> 5h) (4FPU -> 6h) (6FPU -> 8h)>
```

The only difference I can see is that at the end of the "expected" string there's a blank, but not at the end of the "actual" string.

Here's my class which I want to test:

```
package info.rueth.fpucalculator.calc;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Holds an absorption scheme, connecting FPUs to recommended absorption times.
 */
public class AbsorptionScheme {
    private AbsorptionBlock[] absorptionBlocks;

    AbsorptionScheme() {
        // Create empty array
        absorptionBlocks = new AbsorptionBlock[0];
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new absorption block to the absorption scheme.
     * @param maxFPU The maximum FPU for the absorption time
     * @param absorptionTime The absorption time for that FPU.
     */
    public void addBlock(int maxFPU, int absorptionTime) {
        // Copy existing array into new array with one more empty element at the end ...
        AbsorptionBlock[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(absorptionBlocks, absorptionBlocks.length + 1);

        // ... and put new AbsorptionBlock into that empty element
        newArray[absorptionBlocks.length] = new AbsorptionBlock(maxFPU, absorptionTime);

        // Sort by maxFPU and replace object variable
        Arrays.sort(newArray, new AbsorptionBlockSorter());
        absorptionBlocks = newArray;
    }

    /**
     * Picks the absorption time associated to the number of FPUs, e.g.:
     * <p>absorptionScheme: 0-1 FPU - 3 hours; 1-2 FPU - 4 hours; 2-3 FPUs - 5 hours; 3-4 FPUs - 6 hours; >4 FPUs - 8 hours</p>
     * <p>The fpu value is commercially rounded to 0 digits, i.e. 2.49 will be rounded to 2, 2.50 will be rounded to 3.</p>
     * <p>If the fpu value is beyond the last scheme block, the time of the last scheme block in the array is returned.</p>
     * 
     * @param fpus The calculated FPUs.
     * @return The associated absorption time.
     */
    public int getAbsorptionTime(double fpus) {
        // Round up the fpus - it's more secure to get a longer insulin interval
        long roundedFPUs = Math.round(fpus);

        // Find associated absorption time
        for (int i = 0; i < absorptionBlocks.length; i++) {
            if (roundedFPUs <= absorptionBlocks[i].getMaxFPU()) {
                return absorptionBlocks[i].getAbsorptionTime();
            }
        }

        // Seems to be beyond the last block, so return time of the last block
        return absorptionBlocks[absorptionBlocks.length - 1].getAbsorptionTime();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String returnString = "Absorption Scheme:";
        for (int i = 0; i < absorptionBlocks.length; i++) {
            returnString += " (" + absorptionBlocks[i].getMaxFPU() + "FPU -> " + absorptionBlocks[i].getAbsorptionTime() + "h)";
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

And here's my test code:

```
    @Test
    public void addBlock() {
        // Create absorption scheme
        AbsorptionScheme absorptionSchemeActual = new AbsorptionScheme();

        // Add absorption blocks - unsorted on purpose to test sorting!
        absorptionSchemeActual.addBlock(2, 4);
        absorptionSchemeActual.addBlock(3, 5);
        absorptionSchemeActual.addBlock(6, 8);
        absorptionSchemeActual.addBlock(1, 3);
        absorptionSchemeActual.addBlock(4, 6);

        // Create another absorption scheme ...
        AbsorptionScheme absorptionSchemeExpected = new AbsorptionScheme();

        // ... and add blocks, this time sorted!
        absorptionSchemeExpected.addBlock(1, 3);
        absorptionSchemeExpected.addBlock(2, 4);
        absorptionSchemeExpected.addBlock(3, 5);
        absorptionSchemeExpected.addBlock(4, 6);
        absorptionSchemeExpected.addBlock(6, 8);

        // Assert both schemes: They should be identical!
        assertEquals(absorptionSchemeExpected, absorptionSchemeActual);
    }
```

I cannot see any difference, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question showing how you implemented `AbsorptionBlock.equals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assertEquals(Object, Object)` method uses `equals()` of given objects to check equality. Since you have not overridden `equals()` in `AbsorptionScheme` class, `equals()` implementation of `java.lang.Object` is used by `assertEquals()`.

`Object.equals()` returns `true` only when the two objects are the same (same object reference). See below text from Javadoc of `Object.equals()`.

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

In your testcase, `absorptionSchemeActual` and `absorptionSchemeExpected` are two difference objects. Hence `assertEquals()` fails.

Comment: Thanks, Prasad, that's the solution. I added the method equals and it works perfect!